# removing mysterious line break python

Tags: python

I have this code that runs through lines in text file like this:

`09824747 18 n 02 archer 0 bowman 0 003 @ 09640897 n 0000 ~ 10290474 n 0000 ~i 10718145 n         0000 | a person who is expert in the use of a bow and arrow`

```
L = line.split()
L2 = line.split('|')
synset_offset = L[0]
lex_filenum = L[1]
ss_type = L[2]
gloss = L2[1]
```

They way i print these out looks like this

```
print('''<http://example.org/#'''+synset_offset+'''><http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#lex_filenum> "'''+lex_filenum+'''".
<http://example.org/#'''+synset_offset+'''> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#ss_type> "'''+ss_type+'''".
<http://example.org/#'''+synset_offset+'''> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#gloss> "'''+gloss+'''".''')
```

but for some reason a linebreak occurs after `'''+gloss+'''`

and looks like this

```
<http://example.org/#09824747> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#lex_filenum> "18".
<http://example.org/#09824747> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#ss_type> "n".
<http://example.org/#09824747> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#gloss> " a person who is expert in the use of a bow and arrow
".
```

I want to remove that linebreak as it wont allow the text to be formatted otherwise

Comment: Also  - other scritp html-generating languages as PHP and Javascript lack a built-in string templating system, and require this mix of quotes and + signs (or .) you are using. That is not the case with Python - your HTML snippet can become two orders of magnitude more readable if you use string formatting of either type: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.split()` without arguments or `None` as the first argument removes whitespace around the line first, but `.split('|')` does *not*.

Remove it explicitly before splitting:

```
L2 = line.strip().split('|')
```

or after:

```
gloss = L2[1].strip()
```

`.strip()` removes *all* leading and trailing whitespace. You can be more specific and only remove newlines from the end using `.rstrip():

```
gloss = L2[1].rstrip('\n')
```